# php socket_write

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

I'm trying to send some data (text) to the current socket.

Previously making hand shake - OK.

Then send data from client (Chrome, latest version) - `socket_recv` receives it - OK.

Then I'm trying to write to the same socket what I just read by `socket_recv` using `socket_write` - NOTHING.

Any errors (checked using `socket_last_error` and the function returns `TRUE`). It seems like all OK.

But `onmessage` event on the client-side not firing. Silence...

Who used websockets in PHP, please help.

Client:

```
var host = "ws://192.168.0.100:5000/wbs_r1.php";

try {
    var socket = new WebSocket(host);
    message('<p class="event">Socket Status: ' + socket.readyState);

    socket.onopen = function (msg) {
        message('<p class="event">Socket Status: ' + socket.readyState + ' (open)');
        console.log(socket);
        console.log(msg);
    }

    socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
        message('<p class="message">Received: ' + msg.data);
        console.log(socket);
        console.log(msg);
    }

    socket.onclose = function (msg) {
        message('<p class="event">Socket Status: ' + socket.readyState + ' (Closed)');
        console.log(socket);
        console.log(msg);
    }

    socket.onerror = function (msg) {
        message('Error: ');
        console.log(socket);
        console.log(msg);
    }

} catch (exception) {
    message('<p>Error' + exception);
    console.log(exception);
}
```

Server:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
set_time_limit(0); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
$sockets = array(); 
$handshakes = array();

$sockets["wbs1"] = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($sockets["wbs1"], SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($sockets["wbs1"], "0.0.0.0", 5000);
socket_listen($sockets["wbs1"], 20);
socket_set_nonblock($sockets["wbs1"]);

echo $sockets["wbs1"] . "\n";

while(true) {
    $changed_sockets = $sockets;
    $num_sockets = socket_select($changed_sockets, $write = null, $exceptions = null, null);
    //print_r($changed_sockets);
    foreach($changed_sockets as $socket) {
        echo "\n\n\n" . "Current socket: " . $socket . "\n";
        if($socket == $sockets["wbs1"]) {
            if(($client = socket_accept($sockets["wbs1"])) >= 0) $sockets[] = $client;
            echo "Accepting socket ".$socket."\n";
            echo "Client: " . $client . "\n";
        } else {
            $index = array_search($socket, $sockets);
            $len = @socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 2048, 0);
            echo "Received " . $len . " bytes from socket ".$socket.": " . $buffer . "\n";

            if($len == 0) {
                unset($sockets[$index]);
                unset($handshakes[$index]);
                socket_close($socket);
                echo "Closing socket " . $socket . "\n";
            } else if(!isset($handshakes[$index])) {
                $buffer = substr($buffer, strpos($buffer, "Sec-WebSocket-Key: ") + 19);
                $accept = base64_encode(sha1(substr($buffer, 0, strpos($buffer, "\r\n")) . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11', true));

                $upgrade = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" .
                    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
                    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
                    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {$accept}\r\n\r\n" .
                    "Sec-Websocket-Extensions=x-webkit-deflate-frame". chr(0);

                socket_write($socket, $upgrade, strlen($upgrade));
                $handshakes[$index] = true;

                echo "Handshaking: " . $socket . "\n";
            } else {
                $msg = "Hello!!!\n\0";
                $wr = socket_write($socket,$msg);
                if(!$wr) echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
                else echo "Writing to socket " . $socket . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing, its my first question.

Comment: Hey, may be will be better to choice some other solution for websockets? Tomcat or something else?

Comment: Is your client's `onerror` callback running?  Messages from client->server are required to include a 32-bit mask.  Messages from server->client must not use a mask.  This means that you can't simply echo messages but should instead decode them then resend without the mask.

Comment: @simonc, I have no errors. `OnError` not firing.